# react-native-biometrics - check if another faceid is added in ios

Tags: react-native

Lets say i setup FaceId on the phone. Then i registered for biometrics in the app. Everything works fine. But now when i add another FaceId, and when i try to login again, it should be able to detect that a new faceId has been added and it should give me an error or something. How can this be achieved with `react-native-biometrics` library. In android it can be detected if a new fingerprint is added but not when delete a fingerprint. but in ios cannot detect if the faceid is reset or a new one addded.

eg. code

```
const checkKeyExist = yield rnBiometrics.biometricKeysExist()
if (checkKeyExist.keysExist) {
  const epochTimeSeconds = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000).toString()

  try {
    const createSignature = yield rnBiometrics.createSignature({
      promptMessage: 'Sign in',
      payload: epochTimeSeconds
    })
  } catch (err) {
    // Should catch that error here
  }
}
```

any help would be much appreciated